# How do I update Guice for an XText project?

Tags: guice, xtext

I have an XText project that I am trying to write tests for. The problem is that the tests on the compiled code fail with an uninformative trace starting with:

```
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
```

I have read that it is a problem with an old version of Guice (https://github.com/google/guice/issues/757).

However, whilst I have downloaded the latest Guice.jar I cannot understand how to get XText to use it over previous versions.

I have plug-in dependencies such as com.google.inject that I figured should point to the latest Guice.jar, but pointing them there did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: this sounds more like you are missing JDT or your JDT version is too old

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just checked, I have the latest JDT (4.6) installed. Trying to update it didn't do anything.

Comment: no what i meant: is it one the dependencies of the test you execute. directly or indirectly

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I went and added JDT as an external library (I added everything .jar with JDT in the name from the Eclipse plug-ins directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error says: jdt is missing on the classpath of the test project. make sure you add it by means of the build system you use (manifest / pom / build.gradle / ant / ...)

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a plain Eclipse project, following suggestions from other answers means...

1. Open project's manifest (right click on project > Plug-in Tools > Open Manifest)

[image]

2. Add jdt.core to imported packages

[image]

3. Save the manifest, wait for Eclipse to build the project and try again